# Can Integration By Parts be used for a problem with more than two functions?

Tags: calculus, integration

Can Integration by Parts be used to solve a problem that is more than $\int f(x)g'(x) dx$? - Like can it be used to solve something of the form: $\int f(x)g(x)h(x)i'(x)\ dx$ or $\int f(x)g(x)h(x)i(x)j'(x)\ dx$ etc? If yes, how would it be done?
[This question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/878213/generalising-integration-by-parts-for-the-product-of-more-than-two-functions) seems to be addressing the same problem, but I do not understand the answer. Is there a way to answer this question in simple terms?

Comment: Maybe this helps: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integration_by_parts#Product_of_many_functions